# In C# List How can I find duplicates and add attribute value?

Tags: c#

Let's say I have a **List** of the following object:

`Player {id, score}`

I need to find the *duplicated ids*, be able to **add the score** of the duplicated players, and *return* the list without duplicates and with the added scores.

`Player1.id = 1`
`Player1.score = 5`

`Player1.id = 1`
`Player1.score = 6`

`Player2.id = 2`
`Player2.score = 4`

Expected result:

`Player1.id = 1`
`Player1.score = 11`

`Player2.id = 2`
`Player2.score = 4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use GroupBy, here is an example:

```cs
    var result = players.GroupBy(x => x.id)
                         .Select(x => new Player
                         {
                             id = x.Key,
                             score = x.Sum(y => y.score)
                         })
                         .ToArray();
```

Comment: Awesome! This works! But what if I add a third attribute, such as "name". How can I include it in "result"? @Cihan

Comment: such as `name = x.First().name`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
   var result = players
      .GroupBy(x => x.Id)
      .Select(x => new Player(x.Key, x.Sum(s => s.Score)))
      .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try below steps

1. group by I'd
2. sum within grouped values

Ex:. PrayerList.groupby(X=>x.id).select(g=> new prayer{id = g.key, score = g.sum(y=>y.score)}).tolist()